# Weka data import with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, mapping, weka

I have to import different tables (here the Customer table) with the help of Hibernate and transform them into a readable format for the Weka API.
Currently it's possible to get get database result with

```
List<Object[]> myResult = SessionUtils.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().createQuery(
                  "from Customer")
                  .list();
```

There I get an array list with Objects of the type "Customer".
In another class it's possible to read an arff file with my WEKA Code and analyse the data the way I want

```
Instances ins = new Instances(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(".../Customer.arff")));
```

Is there an easy way to transform myResult into the format I need it in "Instances ins"?
Please ask if you need more information.
Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create Instance-Objects like any other Java Object. 
There's an example for that in the javadoc of the Instance - Class:

```
// Create empty instance with three attribute values
Instance inst = new Instance(3);

// Set instance's values for the attributes "length", "weight", and "position"
inst.setValue(length, 5.3);
inst.setValue(weight, 300);
inst.setValue(position, "first");
```

To convert your Collection to an Intances-Object: Iterate through your `myResult`-List, create a new `Instance`-Object for every `Customer` and add it to your `Instances`-Object via the add-method.